# across / dplyr: cannot use !is.na as function, error: "! invalid argument type"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to convert the types of some columns from a date to a boolean (I am only interested to know if there is a date or not). I am able to use `across` to mutate with the function `is.na` but I get an error if I try to invert this with `!is.na`. I have changed my approach to work around this so it is somewhat academic but I find it extremely annoying that I do not understand why this does not work as I expect given that I use `!is.na` in other contexts to great success.

Example data:

```
> df_test
# A tibble: 5 × 6
     id applicant_name invited_privately   invited             interviewed         gender
  <int> <chr>          <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr> 
1     1 A              NA                  NA                  NA                  Man   
2     2 B              NA                  NA                  NA                  Woman 
3     3 C              NA                  NA                  NA                  Woman 
4     4 D              2022-10-03 17:50:00 2022-10-03 17:42:00 2022-12-29 16:20:00 Woman 
5     5 E              NA                  NA                  NA                  Man
```

Convert to logical:

```
> df_test %>% mutate(across(colnames(df_test)[3:5], is.na))
# A tibble: 5 × 6
     id applicant_name invited_privately invited interviewed gender
  <int> <chr>          <lgl>             <lgl>   <lgl>       <chr> 
1     1 A              TRUE              TRUE    TRUE        Man   
2     2 B              TRUE              TRUE    TRUE        Woman 
3     3 C              TRUE              TRUE    TRUE        Woman 
4     4 D              FALSE             FALSE   FALSE       Woman 
5     5 E              TRUE              TRUE    TRUE        Man
```

All I do here is change `is.na` to `!is.na`:

```
> df_test %>% mutate(across(colnames(df_test)[3:5], !is.na))
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(colnames(df_test)[3:5], !is.na)`.
Caused by error in `!is.na`:
! invalid argument type
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I am not an R expert by any means and I do sometimes get a little lost with dplyr conceptually, so I may be making some obvious error here. I appreciate any insight!

Comment: I believe you would need to do `function(x){!is.na(x)}` in the across, you are using two functions `!` and `is.na` which might cause issues

Comment: Correct! Thanks Mike!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?across`:

```
    .fns: Functions to apply to each of the selected columns. Possible
          values are:

            • A function, e.g. ‘mean’.

            • A purrr-style lambda, e.g. ‘~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)’

            • A named list of functions or lambdas, e.g. list(mean =
              mean, n_miss = ~ sum(is.na(.x)). Each function is applied
              to each column, and the output is named by combining the
              function name and the column name using the glue
              specification in ‘.names’.
```

Your use of `!is.na` is not valid R in general, since "negating a function" has little meaning. (What would `!mean` do?)

You have three easy options:

- `across(..., function(z) !is.na(z))`
- `across(..., Negate(is.na))`
- `across(..., ~ !is.na(.))`

Comment: That is very helpful! I guess what I thought I was doing was using the `Negate()` function, but I see what you mean about e.g. `!mean`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an anonymous function for the `!is.na` scenario. Also I'd recommend selecting the variables like so `invited_privately:interviewed`.

```
df_test |> 
  mutate(across(invited_privately:interviewed, is.na))
```

Here is how to do negate the `is.na()`. Both variants are the same, using different notations for anonymous functions.

```
df_test |> 
  mutate(across(invited_privately:interviewed, \(x) !is.na(x)))

df_test |> 
  mutate(across(invited_privately:interviewed, function(x) !is.na(x)))
```

Comment: I had forgotten about lambda functions in R so this is very helpful. Also I have changed my selection. Thanks Till!